# Discontinuous Self-Map On Continuous Functions With Compact-Open Topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be topological Hausdorff spaces with at-least 2 points and equip $C(X,Y)$ with the compact-open topology. What is an example of an injective function $F:C(X,Y)\rightarrow C(X,Y)$ which is not continuous?

I think particularly towards $X=\mathbb{R}^k$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: That depends on $X$ and $Y$. In particular if both are discrete with $X$ finite, then  $C(X,Y)$ is discrete as well and thus every function $C(X,Y)\to C(X,Y)$ is continuous.

Comment: Send all constant functions to the constantly $0$ function but send all other functions to itself, for $X=Y=\Bbb R$, say.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Indeed, I refined the post to require injectivity, or else the question is trivial.

Comment: The question remains trivial. Pick any bijection on $C(X,Y)$ at random. It will almost surely be non-continuous, certainly in situations where $C(X,Y)$ is much smaller than $Y^X$.

Comment: This makes sense, but what would be a concrete example of one (way when $X=Y=\mathbb{R}^n$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $X,Y$ spaces like $\Bbb R^n$, we know that $C(X,Y)$ will be separable metrisable, there at most $\mathfrak{c}$ many continuous self-maps defined on $C(X,Y)$, while there are $2^{\mathfrak{c}} > \mathfrak{c}$ many bijections on $C(X,Y)$.

So "almost all" bijections on $C(X,Y)$ are non-continuous.